Why does my Search Query not returning the most obvious Result?
I use the Wikipedia API to retrieve information about Games and Movies.
I have always a more or less generic Search Query with the Name (in english) and an appendix. An example for the Game "Overlord II":

Overlord II (2009) (video game)

Which contains the name, the year of release and the Type of it (if there is also a Movie named equal and released the same year)
But if I use the Wikipedia API I get these two results at the beginning of the list:

"Overlord (video game series)"
"Overlord II" <- I want this one

The API URL I am using:
https://api.wikimedia.org/core/v1/wikipedia/en/search/page?q={searchQuery}

Why does the API prefer the more generic parent Page over the precise Result of my Query?
Can I precise my Query even more to always get the Pages I want? Can I tell the API that I want to "skip" these Parent Pages?

Okay, so for now I am using a list of results and I can then pick the right one. But this doesn't me feel very good, because for me this means that Wikipedia (API) prefers other Pages than the most obvious one.
